# Understand simple problem on inflation

Tags: statistics

If the average food basket costs $100$ euros at 2nd quarter prices, how much will it cost for 3rd quarter prices? Below is the graph. I know that the answer is $97$ and can be achieved using follows: $$100 \left( 1 - \left(\frac{97.5-95}{95}\right)\right)$$

But can someone explain me the logic behind this?

[image]

Comment: I must be missing something, but why is the answer not $ \frac{95}{97.5} €100 $? If food prices in Q2 cost 97.5% of Q1 prices, and Q3 prices are 95% of Q1 prices, surely €100 in Q2 would be worth $\frac{1}{0.975}€100 $ in Q1, which would then be worth $\frac{0.95}{0.975}€100 $ in Q3?

Comment: @copper.hat I think the confusion arise from the fact that you are measuring in Q1 "currency", while the OP asks for Q3 "currency"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first computation is

$$\left(\frac{97.5-95}{95}\right);$$

this is computing the ratio of the difference between second quarter price and third quarter price, on the third quarter price. That is, you are measuring the change in price between the second and third quarters relative to the third quarter price. If you multiply this ratio by $100$,
$$100\left(\frac{97.5-95}{95}\right),$$ you will get the amount by which this second quarter price (which is $100$) has dropped in the third quarter. You then substract this amount from $100$, the second quarter price:
$$100-100\left(\frac{97.5-95}{95}\right)=100\left(1-\left(\frac{97.5-95}{95}\right)\right).$$

Comment: In the second formula above, why did you multiply by the Q2 cost and not the Q3 cost (since you are looking at change relative to the Q3 price)?

Comment: @copper.hat The first ratio measures the drop in price for Q2 to Q3, in Q3 currency. I then took the Q2 price and transformed into a Q3 price.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. I am a little remedial on this, I think. Surely the 2nd formula measures how much more (in Q3 €) an equivalent food basket would have cost in Q2, if it was purchased for €100 in Q3?

Comment: @MTurgeon: Firstly, why do we calculate the change in price relative to the third quarter price and not the second quarter price. Moreover, what will the answer be if the origianl cost in the second quarter was 120 euros?

Answer (score 1):

A correct and simple way to solve this problem is:

$$ \require{cancel}100 \cancel{\text{ Q2 euros}} \cdot \frac{95 {\text{  Q3 euros}}}{97.5 \cancel{\text{ Q2 euros}}} = 97.44 \text{ Q3 euros} $$

We need to change units from units of Q2 euros to units of Q3 euros. This is like any change of units (eg. from feet to inches). For food, 95 euros in the 3rd quarter is equivalent to 97.5 euros in the 2nd quarter. Multiplying by the conversion factor $\frac{95 {\text{  Q3 euros}}}{97.5 \text{ Q2 euros}}$ is like multiplying by 1. For example:

$$ \require{cancel}2 \cancel{\text{ feet}} \cdot \frac{12 {\text{ inches}}}{1 \cancel{\text{ feet}}} = 24 \text{ inches} $$

This is an easy, less error prone way to change units.

#### Difference with the accepted answer

The accepted answer isn't quite precise. It says the percent increase from Q2 to Q3 is 1 minus the percent increase from Q3 to Q2:

$$ \frac{X_3 - X_2}{X_2} \approx 1 - \frac{X_2 - X_3}{X_3}$$

That's not a bad approximation for $X_2 \approx X_3$ but it's not quite right.